# Is there a way to levearge Google Drive API to allow your application to create Google Docs from within your own system?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

We were using an Iframe, then we started to use the API for Google Drive. We want to allow users to create a Google Doc from within our system w/o leaving our application. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Are you asking for creating a new file inside of an iframe?

Comment: The answer to the question as asked is 'yes'. I suspect the question could benefit from some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new file with one of the Google Docs mimeTypes and wait for the response.

```
POST https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert
{ "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document" }
```

Once response arrives, it'll contain an attribute called `embedLink`. Use embed link on iframe.

All available Google Docs mime types are on https://developers.google.com/drive/mime-types